# Need help with a JQuery Selector that returns all checked checkboxes that are children of a node with a specified class

Tags: asp.net, jquery, jquery-selectors

Annoyingly enough, setting the cssClass property of an ASP.NET checkbox control renders HTML like so instead of just adding the class attribute to the input tag:

```
<span class="myclass">
    <input id="chkBox1" type="checkbox" name="chkBox1" />
 </span>
```

So here I am trying to write a Jquery filter that finds all of the checked checkboxes that are nested inside a span tag with the class "myclass" specified.

This is what I have so far, but it doesn't seem to be working.

```
$(".myclass input[type='checkbox']:checked")
```

Anyone see what I am doing incorrectly?

I'd also accept a solution that tells me how to make the checkbox control just put the dang class attribute on the input control instead of wrapping a span around it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work:

```
$("span.myclass :checkbox")
```

Do you also need them checked? Then like so:

```
$("span.myclass :checkbox:checked")
```

Comment: That did the trick. Thanks!

Just so I understand, though. I thought that adding a space in a selector basically equated to an OR for the attributes on either side of the space. Am I mistaken?

Comment: Space means nesting. See docs: http://docs.jquery.com/Selectors/descendant#ancestordescendant

Answer (score 1):

I actually don't think you need the input type because only a checkbox can be true for :checked so you could write $(".myclass").find("input:checked") and it should probably be fine

Comment: Radio-button can also be checked.

Comment: An equally good answer, but I accepted the other one because the selector style works better in my particular situation than the .find syntax. Definitely still worth the upvote (+1).